# I am not able to use export, but i need an multi language array to be globably accesible to multiple js file, how should i do it?

Tags: javascript

`main.js`

```
class Calendar {
  static locales = {
    en: {
      days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
      daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
      daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
      months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
      weekShort: 'W',
      weekStart:0
    }
  };
}
```

`main.fr.js`

```
Calendar.locales['fr'] = {
    days: ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi"],
    daysShort: ["Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam"],
    daysMin: ["D", "L", "Ma", "Me", "J", "V", "S"],
    months: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Fév", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Jui", "Jul", "Aou", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Déc"],
    weekShort:'S',
    weekStart: 1
};
```

I wanted to do something like that, but I am not able to use export, so my locales is not reading the info from another file. I tried using it as a global variable, still not working

Comment: Is there a reason that you are avoiding using export?

Comment: Hi Gabriel! You say " I tried using it as a global variable, still not working " - How did you try that? So how did you set the global variable and how did you try to access it?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I tried declaring the locales above class declaration(javascript makes everything global if declared in this way)

Comment: @lejlun Yes, the reason I am avoiding using export is that the application is using a custom file reader for js and CSS files, so I have to modify that script(and I am not allowed to do it).

Comment: @Gabriel Can you show the actually code for using the global and did you check it actually made it global? There are things that can stop it from being global in that case, such as using modules; if you declare a "global" in a module, it won't be global.

Comment: Ah, I see you solved it already

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem, I would say is a good one.
Instead of using a js file for storing this info, I tried using JSON.

`main.js`

```
class Calendar {
    static locales;

     $.getJSON("/path/the/json/files/", $.proxy(function (json) {
            Calendar.locales = json;
        }, this));
    }
```

`main.fr.js` -> `main.fr.json`

```
{
  "fr": {
    "days": [
      "Dimanche",
      "Lundi",
      "Mardi",
      "Mercredi",
      "Jeudi",
      "Vendredi",
      "Samedi"
    ],
    "daysShort": [
      "Dim",
      "Lun",
      "Mar",
      "Mer",
      "Jeu",
      "Ven",
      "Sam"
    ],
    "daysMin": [
      "D",
      "L",
      "Ma",
      "Me",
      "J",
      "V",
      "S"
    ],
    "months": [
      "Janvier",
      "Février",
      "Mars",
      "Avril",
      "Mai",
      "Juin",
      "Juillet",
      "Août",
      "Septembre",
      "Octobre",
      "Novembre",
      "Décembre"
    ],
    "monthsShort": [
      "Jan",
      "Fév",
      "Mar",
      "Avr",
      "Mai",
      "Jui",
      "Jul",
      "Aou",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Déc"
    ],
    "weekShort": "S",
    "weekStart": 1
  }
}
```